# Как разбить массив на две части и присвоить их двум переменным?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-form

Имеется массив с текстом например "332+21". Нужно разбить его на две части и получить и в двых переменных: `А = 332` и `В = 21`.

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: как выгляди массив с текстом и причем тут jQuery?

Answer (score 3):

```js
var c = "332+21".split("+");
var a, b;
a = c[0];
b = c[1];
```

Answer (score -1):

Для решения этой задачи не требуется jQuery. Здесь вполне можно обойтись стандартными инструментами JS:

```js
let [a, b] = "332+21".split('+').map(e => +e);
console.info(a, b);
```

Comment: хотя бы старым тогда прогить учиться, а не новьем))

Comment: @Jean-Claude, Зачем учится старому, когда новое уже на прошло с порога в гостиную и уселось с глинтвейном в кресло?

Comment: информации то больше, а как же то, что не все браузеры поддерживают? тут учиться бы языку, а не лепить костыли кроссбраузерности))

Comment: @Jean-Claude, сейчас нормальные люди пишут как белые люди, а транспайлер переделывает на старый лад. Чёрные люди так и продолжают страдать со старым кодом.